# Why is PHP code showing up on my contact form?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on a single page responsive website (from a youtube tutorial) using Bootstrap. The tutorial only goes so far until the front-end. Now I want to work my contact us form, so I added PHP code I found online.

I feel something is wrong with the "echo" line in my code, can anyone direct me as to where the error is??? Sorry if this is a basic question!

HTML code (with PHP code):

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user-name"  id="user-name" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <?php 
        echo $errName;?>
    </div>
 </div><!--end form-group-->

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user-email" id="user-email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address">
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'> $errEmail </p>";?>
    </div>
 </div><!--end form-group-->

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user-url" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Your website</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user-url" id="user-url" placeholder="If you have any">
    </div>
 </div><!--end form-group-->

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Any message</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" 
        cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'> $errMessage </p>";?>
    </div>
 </div><!--end form-group-->

 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <?php echo $result; ?>    
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

the PHP code:

```
<?php
$errName = '';
$errMessage = '';
$errEmail = '';
$result = '';
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : NULL;

if (is_string($submit)) {
    $name = $_POST['user-name'];
    $email = $_POST['user-email'];
    $url   = $_POST['user-url'];
    $message = $_POST['user-message'];
    $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'mahendran.vattekat@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n URL: $url\n Message:\n $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['user-name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['user-email'] || !filter_var($_POST['user-email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['user-message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in     touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

UPDATE: Okay this is very frustrating. I have a local server set up, got these updated codes and they look like they work as a single php file. But when I try to execute the html+php file (along with my website)AND the index.php file it goes crazy because after pushing the submit button I'm left with a blank page. This is incredibly frustrating because I have both index.php and my main php files in the same folder as my XAMPP local server htdocs folder.

Aren't two php files supposed to interact with each other? Why are the error checking codes not working when I use it as a whole website??? I also keep getting "Notice : Undefined variable in (main php file) even though I got the index.php file on the same folder!

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: what is the extension of the file with html +php code, please make sure it is .php and not .html

Comment: If you view source, do you see an error message? Check the syntax near that line (you may have to comment lines out to find where the problem is)

Comment: Ah okay, I just did that, but the php code is still showing up.

Comment: Okay so with inspect element, I can see the PHP code is showing up with the comment syntax, even though my code begins with a <? , under inspect element it shows <!-- ? ... and the errEmail,Name and Message shows up separately as text under the double quotes. Why is it doing that?

Comment: Are you sure all your files are .php?

Comment: I changed it to .php, however how can I display the html file if that's also php? Couldn't I only view an html file if it's with the .html extension???

Comment: No .php can also display HTML. You can even use .phtml if you feel fancy. However, .html files will not execute PHP, so that caused your error.

Comment: So is it that I cannot preview this php code in any way? Because it doesn't seem like I can open the php file like an html file to see what the website looks like...

Comment: I don't know, that's an editor issue, we only solve coding issues here. We all have a different editor.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance I'm not seeing the issue, but replacing this kind of code:

```
<?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
```

By this:

```
<p class='text-danger'>
    <?php echo $errEmail; ?>
</p>
```

Might help you spot the error. It looks much cleaner doesn't it?

You shouldn't need to print HTML code using echo. Don't print using PHP more than you need to.

Also change the if at the top to:

```
if ($_POST)
```

Just to make sure the condition is entered when you submit the form (I don't know if you have a field with name='submit')

Comment: Alright, I changed the code to this, now I don't see the php code, but the error messages don't seem to be working at all. Is there something wrong with the php code syntax?

Comment: You need to submit the form, and it has to fall into your condition to work. check my update.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed sevral problems in your script:

- missing name="" in some input fileds
- duplicated action=""
- added some begining declarations
- generally made it working **now it's Your turn to adopt it to your needs**.

This script is **one file 'index.php'** upload it on your server and experiment/change

```
<?php
    $errName = '';
    $errMessage = '';
    $errEmail = '';
    $result = '';
    $submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : NULL;

    if (is_string($submit)) {
        $name = $_POST['user-name'];
        $email = $_POST['user-email'];
        $url   = $_POST['user-url'];
        $message = $_POST['user-message'];
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'mahendran.vattekat@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n URL: $url\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['user-name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['user-email'] || !filter_var($_POST['user-email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['user-message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }

        // If there are no errors, send the email
        if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in     touch</div>';
            } else {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
            }
        } 
    }
?>

<div class="col-lg-8">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user-name"  id="user-name" placeholder="Enter your name">
            <?php 
            echo $errName;?>
        </div>
     </div><!--end form-group-->

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Email</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user-email" id="user-email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'> $errEmail </p>";?>
        </div>
     </div><!--end form-group-->

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user-url" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Your website</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user-url" id="user-url" placeholder="If you have any">
        </div>
     </div><!--end form-group-->

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Any message</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" 
            cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea>
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'> $errMessage </p>";?>
        </div>
     </div><!--end form-group-->

     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <?php echo $result; ?>    
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe the issue as seen under inspection is that the <?php ... ?> line is showing up as <!--?php...--?> line in  the html code and that's why it's behaving like a comment rather than executable code. How can I fix this?

Sorry, I suppose html doesn't execute php, but I can't open a php file either...

Comment: Added working script, works on my server just adjust it to Yours needs.

Comment: I got this working on a test server as well, however I want it to be along with my website as a separate index.php file. 

Whenever I execute my html+php file on the server, it keeps saying the index.php file variables are undefined... even though it's on the same folder. Is that not how it works? Or do I have to have the php code in the same file?

Comment: I assume You want to make it in this way: index.php (html mixded with php) and validate.php (only php) then just add this line <?php include 'validate.php'; ?> at the top of index.php file and it should work ... and be sure that You point form action back to mentioned index.php (action="index.php")

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove two actions in form tag in html and give one action="index.php"

Comment: I did this. Okay so now when I click submit (without filling anything) my php source code is displaying. Does this mean the error messages are working? 

(I went on "open with" and opened it on Chrome just to see the php file.)